# Multidimensional integration mismatch

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I wanted to evaluate the following integral:

```
Integrate[(2 - 2 Cos[a - b])/(1 + x^2 - 2 x Cos[a - b]), {a, 0, 2 Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

which yields `(4 Pi^2)/x` as the result. However, the same integral upon with substitution of variables and expressed as

```
Integrate[(2 - 2 Cos[y])/(1 + x^2 - 2 x Cos[y]), {a, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

yields `(8 Pi^2)/(1 + x)` as the answer. I can't trace the root for this error. Can somebody clarify why Mathematica gives a wrong answer for the first input?

Comment: Why do you think the substitution of variables in the double integral under consideration is correctly done?

Comment: I vote to close this question because has nothing to do with MMA.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with *Mathematica* but follows from a misunderstanding of the underlying mathematics.

Answer (score 6):

This is simply a math error that has nothing to do with MMA.  Consider the transformation from the $(a,b)$ coordinates to the $(y,z)$ coordinates under the following transformation: $$a=z \;,$$ $$b=z-y
\;.$$  This will give $a-b =y$, but we must also transform the $da\;db=|J|dz\;dy$.  We calculate the determinant of the Jacobian matrix to be -1.  Finally, we must also transform the limits of integration.  Where we had $0<a<2\pi$, we get $0<z<2\pi$.  Where we had $0<b<2\pi$ we get $z<y<z-2\pi$.

So, the transformated integral, using $a$ instead of $z$, is

```
Integrate[-(2 - 2 Cos[y])/(1 + x^2 - 2 x Cos[y]),
 {a, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, a, a - 2 Pi}]
```

The integral evaluates to $\frac{4\pi}{x}$.